# Найти в базе данных значения и вернуть их NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, express, mongoose

У меня есть **GET** запрос:

```
router.get('/category/:categoryId', async (req, res) => {
try {
    // Вернуть здесь все объекты, которые у которых свойство {categoty: 'Обувь'}
} catch (err) {
    res.json(err)
}})
```

Как мне вернуть все объекты у которых свойство объекта category === 'Обувь'? **categoryId** будет принимать значения 1, 2 и 3 и если приходит 1, то надо вернуть все объекты где ***{categoty: 'Обувь'}***. Обычно искал 
по такому примеру, но тут возвращается 1 элемент.

```
const post = await Item.findById(req.params.itemId)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const post = await Item.find({yourparamname : req.params.itemId}), (err, cars) => { err ? err : res});
```

примерно это выглядит так, параметры задаются в виде объекта

`{yourparamname : req.params.itemId})`

Comment: но у меня в req.params.itemId приходит 1, 2 и 3, а уже на их основе должен что то сделать, откуда BD поймет что возвращать если я не передал 'Обувь'?

Comment: значит в запрос нужно передавать этот параметр, доставать его в переменную и подставлять, вместо req.params.itemId. Как вы передаёте запрос?

Comment: Я извиняюсь, не очень вопроса понял но, у меня получается что на фронте я делаю запрос и передаю 1 если клик по кнопке обувь. 2 передаю если одежда и т.д. дальше это число приходит req.params.itemId и каким то образом может даже if/else на первое время я должен сделать так чтобы if(req.params.itemId === 1) {и тут идет возврат всех объектов где {categoty: 'Обувь'}}

Comment: или у вас в базе данных есть поле category name (например обувь) и есть idcategory по которому вы хотите сопоставить и вернуть всю обувь  если categoryID = 1 = Обувь?

Comment: {
name: "3131",
category: "Обувь",
_id: "1312313fxgfgh",
и т.д.
}
вот такой примерно объект и мне надо если пришла 1 вернуть все объекты у которых category: "Обвуь"

Comment: const post = await Item.find({_id: req.params.itemId}), (err, res) => { err ? err : res});
если _id это значение которое передается в  req.params.itemId и соответствует ид категории, я просто не  понял у вас поле id по которому оно генерируется mongo или у вас есть какое то свое поле ид для категорий

Comment: Попробуйте ещё вот так

    const id = {'_id': req.params.itemId};
    const cat= await Item.findOne(id, (err, res) => { err ? err : res});

    res.send(cat);